# How do I unclog a clogged swimming pool vacuum?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, pool, clog

I have a swimming pool which I was vacuuming the other day. Unfortunately, I accidentally vacuumed some larger items (leaves, paper, etc) which caused the whole mechanism to clog, i.e., I can no longer vacuum.

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

We have checked the filters, and they're clean. We suppose that something's actually stuck in the pipes.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an auger to clear the clog in the pipes:

[image]

Loosen the clamp at the metal end and begin inserting the snake (metal coily wire) into the pipe until you hit the blockage (or get stuck in a corner).

Tighten the clamp and turn the plastic handle to spin the snake.  That will help penetrate the blockage (or realign the snake to get it around the corner).

Extract the snake, clean the end off removing the gunk it collects, and repeat until you stop getting more gunk and the water flows through the pipes again.

Answer (score 0):

"PIG" the line as in the answer to this question [How do I remove a wiffle ball from a pool vacuum pipe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15392/how-do-i-remove-a-wiffle-ball-from-a-pool-vacuum-pipe)

Or run a hose from the other end with an expandable bladder.  The bladder fills with water and seals such that water only flows one way.  Look in the plumbing section.